# posting data to Firebase Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, express, google-cloud-firestore, postman

How do I post Booleans, Locations and chosen times to Firestore from postman. Here is my index.js file:

```
exports.createPickUp = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const newPickUp = {
        name  : req.body.pickUpName,
        uploadTime : admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date())
        pickUpStartTime: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
        pickUpEndTime: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
        pickUpLocation: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
        pickUpBefore: req.boolean.pickUpBefore,

    };
    admin
        .firestore()
        .collection("PickUps")
        .add(newPickUp)
        .then((doc) => {
            res.json({ message: `document ${doc.id} created succesfully` });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            res.status(500).json({ error: "something went wrong" });
            console.log(err);
        });
});
```

and somehow by posting something into postman I want to be able to go onto Firestore and be able to see:

name as a string,
pickUpStartTime and pickUpEndTime as a timestamp like they offer on Firestore,
pickUpLocation as co-ordinates like the location feature offers on Firestore,
and pickUpBefore as a boolean

what should I write where the xxxxx's are and how do I subsequently post this from postman (as in what json do I write)

Comment: This is not valid JSON `pickUpStartTime: 16:00 6/16/2020,` There is no way to post that, and then parse it easily in Cloud Functions. The closest you can get is `pickUpStartTime: "16:00 6/16/2020",`, so posting it as a string.

Comment: hey, thanks for your quick response! I have edited the above now to make things clearer. Thank you :))